# Vifm: Separate open file instance allowing vifm to be closed

Tags: terminal, file-management, vifm

```
filextype *.avi,*.mp4,*.wmv,*.dat,*.3gp,*.ogv,*.mkv,*.mpg,*.mpeg,*.vob,
         \*.fl[icv],*.m2v,*.mov,*.webm,*.ts,*.mts,*.m4v,*.r[am],*.qt,*.divx,
         \*.as[fx]

        \ {View using mpv}
    \ mpv --really-quiet %f & disown && exit,

    \ {View using ffplay}
        \ ffplay -fs -autoexit %f,
        \ {View using Dragon}
        \ dragon %f:p,
        \ {View using mplayer}
        \ mplayer %f,
```

I want to be able to launch a video (or anything else) without vifm being open in the background. I somewhat managed to detach the video player from the vifm terminal ( `mpv --really-quiet %f & disown && exit`) but closing vifm closes the video playback....

Is it even possible to completely detach them?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I added `nohup` to the start of the command and that worked!
`nohup mpv --really-quiet %f & disown && exit`